# jquery ajax request succeeds even when page is redirected before request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, request

While trying to figure out how to redirect to a new page after a successful post request, I was trying to understand how ajax works and tried to break the request by trying the code below.

```
window.location.replace(new_url) // redirect BEFORE post request
// jquery post request
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    contentType: "application/json",
})
```

I redirected the page **before** I made the post request with jquery. Surprisingly, the post request was successful and the data were saved in my database (not sure if relevant, but I posted/sent very little data while testing my code).

I thought the correct way is to make a post request, ensure the request is completed successfully, **then** redirect the page. Here, I redirected before I even made a request and the data were still sent to my database. Can someone explain why/how did that happen? Thanks!

Comment: All the code in a section will be run before the browser starts the page navigation. Your ajax request completes because it still had time to run before the browser started unloading javascript from the current page. Note this may not always happen, it just did so this time. Other times it may or may not, either outcome isn't guranteed.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, @PatrickEvans. Definitely helped me understand what's going on better! – hsl 7 mins ago